# How to export from DataTable to PDF in WPF

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, pdf-generation

I am creating a WPF application, in which I need to export data from a DataTable to a PDF file. Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: You can try method shared in this article. [http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/f201d9/export-multiple-data-tables-to-a-single-pdf-page/](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/f201d9/export-multiple-data-tables-to-a-single-pdf-page/)

Answer (score 2):

There is no built in way to do this you can try [iTextSharp](http://sourceforge.net/projects/itextsharp/) for this
have a look here

http://www.dotnetspider.com/resources/29759-Exporting-GridView-PDF.aspx

and here

http://csharpdotnetfreak.blogspot.com/2008/12/export-gridview-to-pdf-using-itextsharp.html

Answer (score 1):

Using iTextSharp,you can do it. Nuget package is also available for ITextSharp. YOu can download it from https://www.nuget.org/packages/iTextSharp. Please, find the code below,

```
public void ExportToPdf(DataTable dt)
{      
    Document document = new Document();
    PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, new FileStream("c://sample.pdf", FileMode.Create));
    document.Open();

    iTextSharp.text.Font font5 = iTextSharp.text.FontFactory.GetFont(FontFactory.HELVETICA, 5);

    PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(dt.Columns.Count);
    PdfPRow row = null;
    float[] widths = new float[] { 4f, 4f, 4f, 4f };

    table.SetWidths(widths);

    table.WidthPercentage = 100;
    int iCol = 0;
    string colname = "";
    PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Products"));

    cell.Colspan = dt.Columns.Count;

    foreach (DataColumn c in dt.Columns)
    {
        table.AddCell(new Phrase(c.ColumnName, font5));
    }

    foreach (DataRow r in dt.Rows)
    {
        if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
           table.AddCell(new Phrase(r[0].ToString(), font5));
           table.AddCell(new Phrase(r[1].ToString(), font5));
           table.AddCell(new Phrase(r[2].ToString(), font5));
           table.AddCell(new Phrase(r[3].ToString(), font5));
       }          
    }  
    document.Add(table);
    document.Close();
}
```