# WPF - Is it possible to export DataGrid into PDF?

Tags: c#, wpf, pdf, pdf-generation

I have a following DataGrid with customized visuals:
[image]

Is it possible to export this DataGrid into a pdf file in a way to keep all the custom visuals?

If it helps someone here is the xaml of my datagrid (The code is messy and propably not optimal, but that's not the point now I just need the help with pdf problem), also another note I am adding columns from C#:

```
        <DataGrid Name="dgMain" AlternationCount="2" AlternatingRowBackground="#f2f2f2" IsReadOnly="True" GridLinesVisibility="None" VerticalGridLinesBrush="White">
        <DataGrid.ColumnHeaderStyle>
            <Style TargetType="DataGridColumnHeader">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="LightGray"/>
                <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="18"/>
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
                <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
                <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
                <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
                <Setter Property="Height" Value="50"/>
                <Setter Property="Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="DataGridColumnHeader">
                            <Grid>
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <Border BorderThickness="1" Padding="3,0,3,0" Height="{TemplateBinding Height}" Grid.Column="0">
                                    <Border.Background>
                                        <SolidColorBrush Color="#c7d9f1"/>
                                    </Border.Background>
                                    <ContentPresenter VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalAlignment}" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"/>
                                </Border>

                                <Thumb x:Name="PART_RightHeaderGripper" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Width="2" BorderThickness="1" Cursor="SizeWE" BorderBrush="{Binding VerticalGridLinesBrush, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}}"/>
                            </Grid>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style>
        </DataGrid.ColumnHeaderStyle>
        <DataGrid.CellStyle>
            <Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
                <Setter Property="Padding" Value="10" />
                <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="16" />
                <Setter Property="Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
                            <Border Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}">
                                <ContentPresenter></ContentPresenter>
                            </Border>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style>
        </DataGrid.CellStyle>
        <DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```

Comment: Do you need only the visuals or do you need selectabel text in the PDF. If you just need the visuals, you could render the control into an image and use this to create a pdf with a free PDF library. For example `iTextSharp (now iText7 => https://github.com/itext/itext7-dotnet)`

Comment: There are numerous solutions on the web that can help you with that (many of them are not free but you can find some open source solution). You could also create an XPS document from your data and then convert it into a PDF. It might be a little bit tricky, but it's doable.

Comment: @SebastianSiemens An Image could work for what I am doing right now, but I would still be interested to learn how to export it with selectable text.

Comment: @JohnDoe If I should create a solution for readable PDF, I would first export it to a readable file-format and then convert this to PDF. For example convert your datagrid to Excel: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/exporting-datagrid-to-excel-in-wpf/ You have to apply visual styles yourself, as xaml styles are not convertable to excel (I have not found a solution so far) With Excel you implement a method for opening the file and save it as PDF.

Comment: @JohnDoe Another way is to create a table within a PDF-Document with iText7 or other PDF-Libraries. But then you have to apply the styles within your code yourself

Comment: Exporting data from a datagrid is a fairly common request users come up with. One of the things to explore is whether this would really be best done as a separate report. Often you find it's easier and more flexible to build something in ms reports or crystal than start from a datagrid. Not always. But that looks like a fairly simple layout.

Answer (score 0):

I have modified this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4720463/how-to-export-from-datatable-to-pdf-in-wpf) to cater dynamic columns count in the datagrid which suggest iTextSharp nuget package to install.

> https://www.nuget.org/packages/itext7/

```
    public void ExportToPdf(DataTable dt)
    {
        Document document = new Document();
        PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, new FileStream("c://sample.pdf", FileMode.Create));
        document.Open();

        Font font5 = FontFactory.GetFont(FontFactory.HELVETICA, 5);

        PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(dt.Columns.Count);

        Array floatArray = Array.CreateInstance(typeof(float), dt.Columns.Count);
        //float[] widths = new float[] { };
        for (int i = 0; i < dt.Columns.Count; i++)
            floatArray.SetValue(4f, i);

        table.SetWidths((float[])floatArray);

        table.WidthPercentage = 100;
        PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Products"));

        cell.Colspan = dt.Columns.Count;

        foreach (DataColumn c in dt.Columns)
        {
            table.AddCell(new Phrase(c.ColumnName, font5));
        }

        foreach (DataRow r in dt.Rows)
        {
            if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < dt.Columns.Count; i++)
                {
                    table.AddCell(new Phrase(r[i].ToString(), font5));
                }
            }
        }
        document.Add(table);
        document.Close();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example using iText7 for any future viewers. Similar to @farrukh-niaz 's answer.

```
//Imports
using iText.Kernel.Pdf;
using iText.Layout;
using iText.Layout.Element;
using iText.Layout.Properties;
using iText.IO.Font;
using iText.Kernel.Pdf.Canvas.Draw;
using iText.Kernel.Colors;
using iText.Kernel.Font;
using iText.IO.Font.Constants;

//Export to PDF function
public void ExportToPdf(DataTable dt)
{
            PdfWriter writer = new PdfWriter(dest);
            PdfDocument pdf = new PdfDocument(writer);
            Document document = new Document(pdf);
            PdfFont font = PdfFontFactory.CreateFont(StandardFonts.HELVETICA);
            PdfFont bold = PdfFontFactory.CreateFont(StandardFonts.HELVETICA_BOLD);                       

            Table table = new Table(dataGrid.Columns.Count);            

            foreach (DataColumn c in dt.Columns)
            {
                table.AddCell(new Paragraph(c.ColumnName.ToString()).SetFont(bold).SetBackgroundColor(ColorConstants.GRAY).SetTextAlignment(iText.Layout.Properties.TextAlignment.CENTER));
            }

            foreach(DataRow r in dt.Rows)
            {
                if(dt.Rows.Count > 0)
                {
                    for(int i = 0; i<dt.Columns.Count; i++)
                    {
                        table.AddCell(new Paragraph(r[i].ToString()).SetFont(font).SetBackgroundColor(ColorConstants.WHITE).SetTextAlignment(iText.Layout.Properties.TextAlignment.CENTER));
                    }
                }
            }

 document.Add(table);
 document.Close();
}
```